# Why Does fancyvrb Turn Comments into Non-comments?

Tags: comments, fancyvrb, bugs

### When I execute the following code, I get a nice `.pdf` as a Result:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
sdfsdfs
\end{Verbatim} 
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF_OUTPUT]

### Below is the Same Code with Some Comments Added Using `%`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim} % Upper case `V` references package{fancyvrb}
sdfsdfs
\end{Verbatim} % Upper case `V` references package{fancyvrb}
\end{document}
```

### After Comments are Added, I Get the Following Error Message:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `sdfsdfs' between \begin{Verbatim}[<key=value>] and line end

.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.5 sdfsdfs
```

I tried doing a make clean (delete all temp `.aux` files, `.gz`, `.synctex`, etc...

### Below are Descriptions of the Software I am Using:

[image: tex_works_version_image]
[image: miktex_version_image]

```
      --------------------------------------------------
      |                   `fancyvrb'                   |
      |                  Version 3.1                   |
      |                  Nov 17, 2018                  |
      |                                                |
      | Timothy Van Zandt (Princeton University - USA) |
      |                                                |
      |     Packaging, documentation and support       |
      |       Denis Girou (CNRS/IDRIS - France)        |
      |            <Denis.Girou@idris.fr>              |
      |        Sebastian Rahtz (Elsevier - GB)         |
      |       Herbert Voss, Berlin (hvoss@tug.org)     |
       --------------------------------------------------


--- fancyvrb.sty
3.1a 2018/11/20   - small changes to the documentation (hv)  
3.1  2018/11/17   - load package xcolor only if it is not done already (hv)  
3.0  2018/11/01   - remove the example part from francyvrb (hv)  
[etc...]

--- fancyvrb-ex.sty
0.01 2018/11/01  - first CTAN version
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The error log already gives the answer: ``Extraneous input `sdfsdfs' between \begin{Verbatim}[<key=value>] and line end``. You have extra code added after the `\begin{Verbatim}` command which is not allowed. Moving the comment one line up should fix the problem (and perhaps a similar solution for the `\end{Verbatim}` is needed).

Comment: @Guido are you sure? (I tried that and it didn't work for me, and I don't see that documented?)

Comment: Just for future reference: The version of your editor (TeXworks) is usually not relevant for issues like this. More often that not the MikTeX version is also not relevant. Package versions are more interesting. A very clean solution to show all involved package versions is by adding `\listfiles` to the top of your MWE and copying the file list at the end of the `.log` file. That saves you hunting down all `.sty`s and including their headers.

Comment: LaTeX is the first language I have ever encountered where comments are not **always** ignored. It was a very disconcerting experience. I see now that a `verbatim` environment turns **ALL** language keywords, etc... including the begin-comment command `%`, into mere string characters.

Comment: @IdleCustard that is why you almost always need a full document example in a question and a fragment is not so helpful, latex is completely context sensitive, _no_ characters have fixed syntax it does not have to be `\ ` to delimit commands or `{` `}` to delimit arguments, all such character settings can be changed at any point. However many languages have an equivalent to verbatim  eg xml/html  has `<![CDATA[...]]>` inside which comment syntax `<!-- ... -->` is not a comment but just text.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

You get an error for text on that line irrespective of whether it is a comment.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim} xxx
sdfsdfs
\end{Verbatim} 
\end{document}
```

Turning comments in to non-comments is more or less the main feature of a verbatim environment, the whole point of such an environment is that special characters like `%` just become normal characters that typeset as themselves and not acting with their usual special behaviours.

Comment: I see! The `% [blah blah blah]` is actually **inside** of the `\verb` block. The comment began **AFTER** the `\begin` statement!